# PHP: How do I code a link for a specific array stored in a text file without hardcoding it?

Tags: php, arrays, hyperlink

This question may have been answered, but I have been Googling and searching this site for over a week now and have not come across anything that applies to this situation. Yes, this is a homework assignment, and I have exhausted my resources (the entire class is confused). Any help or links to relevant resources would be appreciated.

**Problem:** I have a program where the user can submit "bug reports". These bug reports are all written to the same text file and are each treated as an array. Each report is also displayed with a "Details" link. I need to write a hyperlink that will essentially assign the link to the index value of the array without hardcoding it (because the link will need to work for future updates) and then have that specific report displayed in a separate page. I'm submitting a photo of the display table with the link in it so that there's a visual of this allow with the specific code for the display table.

[Image of display table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1ZGh.png)

```
$count = count($ReportArray);
    for($i = 0; $i < $count; ++$i) {
         $CurReport = explode("~", $ReportArray[$i]);

         //bug description line and details link
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td><p style='text-align: center;'><strong>Bug Description: </strong></td>";
        echo "<td colspan='6' style='text-align: center;'>".htmlentities($CurReport[0])."<br/></td>\n";
        //$CurArray = implode("~", $CurReport);
        //assign details link an array - no idea how
        $num = count($ReportArray); //total number of reports
        echo '<td style="text-align: center;">';
        echo '<p><a href="BugReport.php?recordNum="'.$j.'">Details</a></p>';
        echo "</td></tr>\n";

        //other bug report fields
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td></td>";
        echo "<td style=\"text-align:center;\">".htmlentities($CurReport[1])."<br /></td>\n";
        echo "<td style=\"text-align:center;\">".htmlentities($CurReport[2])."<br /></td>\n"; 
        echo "<td style=\"text-align:center;\">".htmlentities($CurReport[3])."<br /></td>\n"; 
        echo "<td style=\"text-align:center;\">".htmlentities($CurReport[4])."<br /></td>\n";  
        echo "<td style=\"text-align:center;\">".htmlentities($CurReport[5])."<br /></td>\n"; 
        echo "<td style=\"text-align:center;\">".htmlentities($CurReport[6])."<br /></td>\n"; 
        echo "<td></td>"; 
        echo "</tr>\n";

        //display updates
        echo "<tr>";
        $line_count = count($ReportArray);
        if($line_count > 7) {
            echo "<tr>";
             echo '<td style="text-align:center; text-weght:bold;">Update</td><td>';
             echo htmlentities($CurReport[$line_count - 1]).'<br/>\n';
             echo "</td>"; 
             echo "</tr>\n";
        }
    }
```

So here's how the program works:

**bug_List.php:** Has the form for bug reports and then a table to
    display the submitted and validated reports. These reports all
    written and read from the same text file. **BugReportCreate.php**:
    This file validates the input and writes it the text file. **BugReport.php:** This file is used to display each individual report and allows the user to submit updates for the report currently displayed. **BugReportUpdate.php**: writes/appends the update to the specific report from BugReport and displays the updated report. bug_List.php will also display the updated report(s)

Comment: can show the sample data format for reportArray

Comment: Moeen, the format is "$Description~$PName~$Version~$Hardware~$System~$Frequency~$Solution\n";                                                                                                              So the arrays in the text file look like this                                                     Test 1~AutoCode~1.0~Server~Mac OSX~once a month~uknown
Test 2~Java Helper~3.0~Server~N/A~once a week~go back to previous version

Comment: $j is the veriable you are supposing to contain link details ?

Comment: That is my attempt. Currently it's just a placeholder so that I can show what I want to do. There's no value assigned to $j anywhere in the program. I would think I'd be able to do something with the indexes (like Test 1 and all the input associated with it is would be [0]), but maybe I'm approaching this wrong?

Comment: if you want to use indexs then I think you have to use the foreach instead of for loop.

Comment: ```foreach($ReportArray as $index => $report) {
 echo '<p><a href="BugReport.php?recordNum="'.$index.'">Details</a></p>';
}```

Comment: It looks like all I may need to do is replace the $j with $ReportArray[$i]. When I click on the link with $ReportArray[$i] in place, it takes me to a page where only the specific array is printed out. I thought I tried that earlier, but maybe there was a syntax error I didn't see. Anyway, thank you for feedback. I don't think I would have seen it otherwise.